# Google Cloud Datastore v1betav3 Quota Exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

After migrating to Cloud Datastore v1betav3 using GRPC with the latest from

[github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/datastore]

(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-golang/commit/581cbbbaf53b821281c5df8f4bb9fa69c2d5f49c),

I see regular ***`rpc error: code = 8 desc = Quota exceeded`*** errors for many Datastore writes (reads seem fine). Nothing else from an application perspective has changed.

Looking at the Datastore usage under "console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails" I see very modest usage (54,239 API calls total):

[image: Very Modest Datastore Usage]

Lastly, there isn't any usage showing under the API Manager.

I'm at wits end. How can I find out *which* quota was exceeded?

Comment: Have you set up billing? If not, you have likely exceeded the 50K free Write Operations per day. Note, operations not Entities (see docs). On a plane, sorry I can't help more